# Detect if uploaded file is an image in PHP

Tags: php

How do I detect if an uploaded file is an image using PHP?

I do not want to use `imagesize()` or check on the file extension.

Comment: What does "an image" exactly mean? Which formats?

Comment: What do you mean by "any format"? What about e.g. TIFF, PCX, PSD? What about RGB/CMYK images, is a CMYK JPEG (won't work in Internet Explorer) a valid image? Do you need to show the images in a browser? What about animated formats like animated GIF?

Comment: What’s wrong with `getimagesize`?

Comment: @Jean do you intend to answer my questions? They are there for a reason.

Comment: @pekka the image can be in any format, and I dont want to use  getimagesize.  Is there an alternative.

Comment: @Jean when you say "any format", the only real alternative is Imagemagick. No built-in PHP component can deal with as many formats as it can. As far as I know, there is no PHP component at all that can do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't be silly, use a **tool especially made for this purpose** - getimagesize()

Comment: i thought that will just check the image size? not whether or not its an image?

Comment: @jiewmeng where is your logic? We can't have a size without an image, can we?

Comment: @jiwemeng from the manual: `... will determine the size of any given image file and return the dimensions along with the file type and a height/width text string ...`

Comment: assuming if the image is corrupted or contains malware

Comment: @Jean there is nothing bad in "malware" as long as you do not include these images in your scripts. And There is no sense in mentioning corrupted images. Any method you use will have to deal with it.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [ImageMagick identify tool](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php) to obtain information on a wider variety of image formats than getimagesize() supports, e.g.

```
$uploaded=$_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"];
$info = `identify $uploaded`;
```

Here's some sample output for a JPEG

```
img029.jpg JPEG 1240x1753 1240x1753+0+0 8-bit PseudoClass 256c 27.3KiB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Comment: Good solution - provided ImageMagick is installed and external binaries can be invoked, of course.

Comment: @Kieran not if he wants to detect more image formats than those supported by getimagesize().

Comment: @Kieran Allen: the OP has specified (in a comment) that "the image can be in any format"; I'm pretty certain that `getimagesize` doesn't support PCX, for example.

Answer (score 4):

If you are talking about images that are going to be displayed in the browser, and you want to make as sure as possible they are valid images, I recommend opening them in GD using the appropriate `imagecreatefrom*()` function and saving them back in the desired target format.

That not only makes sure they are images - this won't work if the input data is broken - but it also filters out any possible shenanigans exploiting leaks in the browsers' graphics libraries, and removes Metadata contained in the image (which often contains sensitive info like author, program(s) used to create the image, camera, location and shooting time) and makes sure the image can be viewed in the browser (CMYK JPG uploads, which will not display in any Version of IE, won't work.)

A potential downside of this is that JPEG images may suffer from a slight loss of quality (GD's JPG encoding quality is not good) and there may be problems with images with transparencies.

Comment: +1 for doing the re-encoding. This can also be done by the IMagick extension, which is less resource heavy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mime_content_type](http://www.php.net/mime_content_type) and verify the types of the uploaded file. Since mime_content_type is deprecated you can use its alternate **[finfo_open](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php)**.

Comment: "This function has been deprecated"

Comment: Use `fileinfo()` instead, it's the replacement for mime_content_type